# In asp.net how to get drives collections from computer to my DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I've a DropDownList and i need to fill it with number of drives available in my computer like C:\, D:\ etc... so how can i do this one? help me.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.IO.DriveInfo` class.

```
System.IO.DriveInfo []drives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach(var drive in drives)
  {
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(drive.Name);
  }
```